# Cannot boot onto Windows HDD

Tags: boot, grub2

I have just installed Ubuntu 12.04 onto a new hard drive, with Windows XP on a separate hard drive. I physically set the Ubuntu drive as primary and it shows as sda.  The boot loader is on this drive too.  I left the Windows drive completely alone.

On boot, Windows XP Proffessional is listed as one of the options, but when I choose this an error is shown.
error: no such device F47836067835C85E
error: hd1 cannot get C/H/S values

I am able to boot into Ubuntu.

I have disconnected the Ubuntu HDD and reconnected it to the primary position on the motherboard so that I can re-access Windows!

Please can anyone help?  I gave up on Linux 8 years ago, and whilst it seems easier in some ways, there are still huge complications!

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't matter what boot loader you're on when installing an OS on two separate hard drives. Each drive will have its own boot loader.

**You should make your BIOS to make you choose at startup which hard drive to boot on.**

So you get a "no such device" error because a separate hard drive is out of its scope for any boot loader.

I don't know much about BIOS configurations for all computers, but fiddling around BIOS setup you should work something out. (post a screenshot when you're stuck)

Alternative: Each time your PC is booting, repeatedly press the *boot device selection menu* key (probably F9, F10, F12 or Esc) and choose your preferred drive to boot on each time.

Comment: Thank you very much Doruk.   I reconnected the Ubuntu drive as a 2nd drive on main board, but wasn't recognised.  In Setup I changed that drive to 'on', although in the 'details' part of Setup it was listed as 'unknown' (unlike the other drive that listed make and size).  However when I rebooted I was automatically taken to a boot options menu and able to select either Ubuntu or Windows XP. So it seems that the reason I could not boot the Windows HDD was that I had not 'turned it on' in Setup. Dual booting with two hdds with Linux & XP CAN be done without entering bios each time! Thanks again.

Comment: "A boot loader cannot tell your computer to redirect you to another distinct hard drive for booting." This is false.

Comment: @qwazix Thank you, I edited my question. But I'll leave the rest the way it is since the main point holds.